# Validating trello board API responses in Python unittest

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-unittest, trello

I am writing a unittest that queries the [trello board API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board) and want to assert that a particular card exists.

The first attempt was using the `/1/boards/[board_id]/lists` rewuest which gives results like:

```
[{'cards': [
    {'id': 'id1', 'name': 'item1'},
    {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'item2'},
    {'id': 'id3', 'name': 'item3'},
    {'id': 'id4', 'name': 'item4'},
    {'id': 'id5', 'name': 'item5'},
    {'id': 'id6', 'name': 'item6'}],
 'id': 'id7',
 'name': 'ABC'},
 {'cards': [], 'id': 'id8', 'name': 'DEF'},
 {'cards': [], 'id': 'id9', 'name': 'GHI'}]
```

I want to assert that 'item6' is indeed in the above mentioned list. Loading the json and using assertTrue, like this:

```
element = [item for item in json_data if item['name'] == "item6"]
self.assertTrue(element)
```

but I receive an error: 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'.

Then discovered using the `/1/boards/[board_id]/cards` request gives a plain list of cards:

```
[
    {'id': 'id1', 'name': 'item1'},
    {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'item2'},
    ...
]
```

How should I write this unittest assertion?

Comment: my_list is already a Python list, there is not need for json.loads(). Json.loads() just works for JSON serialized strings. Try: `element = [item for item in my_list[0]['items'] if item['name'] == "item6"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neatest option is to create a class that will equal the dict for the card you want to ensure is there, then use that in an assertion. For your example, with a list of cards returned over the api:

```
cards = board.get_cards()
self.assertIn(Card(name="item6"), cards)
```

Here's a reasonable implementation for the `Card()` helper class, it may look a little complex but is mostly straight forward:

```
class Card(object):
    """Class that matches a dict with card details from json api response."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, dict):
            return other.get("name", None) == self.name
        return NotImplemented

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({!r}, {!r})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.key, self.value)
```

You could add more fields to validate as needed.

One question worth touching on at this point is whether the unit test should be making real api queries. Generally a unit test would have test data to just focus on the function you control, but perhaps this is really an integration test for your trello deployment using the unittest module?

Comment: Thank you, though I have to say I'm just a beginner and I don't understand a lot from your code yet (like return "{}({!r}, {!r})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.key, self.value). I also somehow managed to solve the problem by myself. :)  I was so fixed on this list I forgot that I could do this easier.

Comment: Was guessing at bit at your problem so my answer is likely more generic than you need, knowing its the trello board api helps. For what the format string means, see [`str.format()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) - the method makes the object have a sensible output when passed to `repr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import unittest
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

class Basic(unittest.TestCase):

    url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/[my_id]/cards?fields=id,name,idList,url&key=[my_key]&token=[my_token]'
    response = urlopen(url)

    resp = response.read()
    json_ob = json.loads(resp)

    el_list = [item for item in json_ob if item['name'] == 'card6']

    def testBasic(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.el_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So what I did wrong: I focused too much on the list itself which I got after using the following code:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import json

url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/[my_id]/lists"

params = {"cards":"open","card_fields":"name","fields":"name","key":"[my_key]","token":"[my_token]"}

response = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
pprint(response.json())
```